# Finding matching records in a chain to form a parent user

Tags: sql-server, query, sql-server-2017

I need to find commonality across 3 columns of data. For instance, user 1 and user 2 have the same email. user 2 and user 3 have the same device id.  So I want to assign a unique parentuserid of 1 to user 1, 2, and 3. See below for sample data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #usr
SELECT 'u1' AS userid, 'email1' AS email, 'device1' AS device INTO #usr UNION ALL
SELECT 'u2' AS userid, 'email1' AS email, 'device2' AS device UNION ALL
SELECT 'u3' AS userid, 'email99' AS email, 'device2' AS device UNION ALL
SELECT 'u4_nomatch' AS userid, 'email77' AS email, 'device77' AS device  
 


-- expected results
-- new parentuserid    userid
--  1                u1
--  1                u2
--  1                u3
--  2                u4_nomatch
```

This parentuserid = 1 is a set of 3 users, but this could actually be *n* (50+). I thought maybe cross join with window functions would be needed here or maybe recursive CTE but I haven't had any luck. It's hard to Google this sort of problem.

SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1):

These users form a graph. They are linked by edges to common attributes (email, device etc.). The question boils down to finding disjoint subgraphs within the data, and assigning each a label.

There's an [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35457468/2234058) which addresses this. The web will have many more if you care to search.

SQL Server 2019 introduced [SHORTEST_PATH()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-shortest-path) which would simplify the query.

Comment: Thanks, that points me in the right direction!